# How can I reset my skill points and re-assign them?

Tags: underworld-empire

In Underworld Empire (iOS and Android game), you can level up your Energy, Stamina, Defense, Attack and HP. Each level, you get 5 points to spend.

I feel like I messed up early in the game to get ahead, and I'd like to tweak the number. I noticed I can't use Favor points to reset them, and I do not want to lose my character and all its stats just for some more points. So, without resetting the game or starting over, **is there a way to reassign my skill points?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the developers, it's not possible.

http://underworldempireforums.com/showthread.php?33193-Reset-skill-points